# Use an image in HTML area tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

I am using maphilight from `jQuery` to work on a map and it works perfectly fine for me. I just don't want to use a shape to display on the map, I would like to display an image (instead of a circle or a rectangle). Is there any way to do this?

Actual site is here: `www.abitraum.com/karte.php`

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using map area you could use absolute css values to put a image on top of your map.

Underneath your main map div you could put another div with an image e.g.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:300px; top:400px;"><img src="xyz.jpg" /></div>
```

Repeat this for all the images you want to do this for.
The `left:300px` means it it 300 pixels from the left side of the screen, `top:400px` means it is 400 pixels from the top of the screen. Although if you plan to have the image in the center of the page or something like that, it might be more useful to use `margin-right:300px` instead of `left:300px;`

Also I would recommend using a CSS file rather than putting things directly into the style of the div.